# My text messages are received by my wife's iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, messages

My wife receives my SMS text messages on her iPhone and iPad. How can I change this?

I do not get her messages on my device

Comment: Are you talking about iMessages or normal Text Messages? If iMessages, the iMessage options might include your email/phone number/apple id, which could cause this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you.They are regular text messages. I think it is an icloud issue. Any time I send or receive a txt msg it goes to her ipad and iphone, but not the reverse.

Comment: Seems weird, yeah. Try contacting your operator perhaps? Normal text messages shouldn't behave that way. :)

Comment: Oh oh! So now she knows?

Comment: When you say "My wife receives my text messages on her iPhone and iPad" - do you mean she receives text messages sent by others and meant for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you're sharing an AppleID for iMessage this is expected behavior.  You can also double check to make sure you don't have any conflicting settings.

From iMessage settings, verify Text Message Forwarding:

Navigate to Settings (app) > iMessage > Text Message Forwarding

Then verify your send and receive addresses:

Navigate to Settings (app) > iMessage > Send & Receive

Those are the 3 pieces that would be causing an issue on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Are the devices on the same network and using the same iCloud-ID? If so, it might be the continuity-feature that syncs text-messages between all known devices on the iCloud-account.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same iTunes account on both devices. If that's the case remove the iTunes account from iPad and see what happens. If removing iTunes account fixes the issue then this is caused by iMessage.